# Get mail message to reply, Malikit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, mailkit

I want to reply a sent mail message using Mailkit, I already read the docs http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Frequently-Asked-Questions.htm#Reply but the thing is how can I get the `MimeMessage` object from the mail server?

When I am sending the mail I save the `MessageId`

```
var msgid = message.MessageId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
client.Send(message);
```

but how can I get that specific message from the mail server?

Answer (score 0):

The only reference I see in the documentation is that you can get a message from a folder like this:

```
foreach (var uid in folder.Search (SearchQuery.NotSeen)) 
{
    var message = folder.GetMessage (uid);
}
```